# jquery.jstree.js .replace(/^#/,"") Removes Anchor Links (to a diffrent page) From URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, anchor, submenu

The issue is that we are using jquery.jstree.js for our menus. The developer wanted to set it so that the menus would expand and contract depending on which page you are on. The problem is that the code, specifically

```
.replace(/^#/, "")
```

in the following

```
s = $.map($.makeArray(s), function (n) { 
    return "#" + n.toString()
        .replace(/^#/,"")
        .replace(/\\\//g,"/")
        .replace(/\//g,"\\\/")
        .replace(/\\\./g,".")
        .replace(/\./g,"\\.")
        .replace(/\:/g,"\\:"); 
});
```

Causes the Anchor Links to get removed from the url (if you are linking to an anchor tag on a different page.)

I removed the # from this bit of code in this line, and that fixed the anchor links but it caused the menu to stop working the same way. It seems to work sometimes but for instance, when we go to the page via anchor link that has the anchor tag in it, the side menu will be closed rather than open.

Does anyone know of a way to allow the anchor links to still work but to still have the menu functionality?

Comment: What functionality is that abomination of chained `replace()` calls supposed to have?

Comment: I am not sure @Rory. The developer before me set this up so that the menu would behave as he wanted it to. It is a side menu that uses the http://www.jstree.com/ menu. Apparently the menu was open, showing all of the menu items rather than set to only display the main menu items and then open when you clicked on the main menu item displaying the sub menu items. I take it from your question the code used is not customary?